# Use custom emoji Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm building a chat app for Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime, no Silverlight) and now I'm facing a problem, I have created an emoji panel with image as emoji.
When I select one emoji from the panel it appear in the text block as a standard emoji.

There is any way to use the image that i have used in the emoji panel instead of showing the standard emoji?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to use RichTextBlock with an InlineUIContainer for the images